# About promises's execution order

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, event-loop

I'm trying to understand the JS event loop, and

```js
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        console.log(0)
        return Promise.resolve(4)
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        console.log(1)
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(2)
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(3)
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(5)
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(6)
    })
```

Why the result is `0 1 2 3 4 5 6`

Why `Promise.resolve(4)`'s callback always be the 5th

Comment: I don't think you are guaranteed for that.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: If I may, your question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75693852/about-js-event-loop-why-different-result was showing a very interesting and surprising behavior (though it didn't need the queueMicroTask) and it was close from being reopened after your edit (2 / 3 required votes). It might still need a bit of polishing, but it would be great if you could undelete it.

Comment: @Kaiido Fancy. I didn't know that one can reopen questions while they are deleted! And just yesterday I learned that it's possible to edit the duplicate list of deleted questions…